# wso2 4.8.1 clone mediator sequential="true"

Tags: wso2, clone

I have a process with 2 steps but I only must execute the second one when the first one finished
   I use clone mediator (clone sequential="true") but target 2 start execute before target one has finished.
   I don't understand this behavour.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call mediator does not wait synchronously for the response : the mediation in the first target ends its execution and the second target is executed. 
When a response come back in the esb, the mediation in the first target, located after call mediator, is then executed.

If you absolutly need to wait for the response before executing the second target, you can use callout (ESB 4.8.1) or call blocking="true" (ESB 4.9.0)

But if what you need to achieve is "service chaining" don't use clone : use send receive="MyResponseSequence". As soos as the response will come back in the ESB, it will be processed in "MyResponseSequence". You can even use call mediator without your "clone" : the mediation located after call will be executed as soon as the response arrive in the ESB (but not before !).

Comment: Thank you very much, I test callout mediator and solved my problem

Comment: I still having problems I need the clone because the second sequence need the original message (the original message has a file) but only has to be executed is the first sequence callout call return a concrete value. ¿is there a way to share information between messages? I need information of the first sequence callout call in the second sequence

Comment: If you need something from the first target in the second one, I think it is a design problem. If you need to made a callout, look at something in the response and then, continue with the initial message : save it and then, restore it. You can use enrich mediator to store a message in a property or restore it. You can also use property mediator : expression="$body" and type="OM". But if you really want to continue with clone mediator, try to store something in a property with scope "operation" (it works with iterate mediator) : I think you should access it's value in the second target